# Displaying WordPress categories in a definition list

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

First time poster, long time reader.

I am converting my static html file to a dynamic wordpress site. the markup I wrote will list categories in a definition list where the wp category name is a `<dt>` and the wp category description is a `<dd>`. My problem is that the wp_list_categories function is not as flexible as I would like, and the extent to which I know php is limited to tweaking built-in functions of wp. What I am looking for is a custom function to accomplish my goal of using a definition list to list wp categories with their category description. Then I can drop that function in the functions.php file and use it throughout the site.

Any help would be much appreciated.

thx!

john

Answer (score 1):

`get_the_category()` returns an array of all category objects related to the current post. Use it in the Loop.

Edit: Usage here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Comment: any chance you can provide and example?

Comment: The wordpress page shows how to loop over the returned array: `foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { `. The category description can be pulled using `$category->category_description` within this category loop. You can easily put the HTML code in.